# GoogleTest: CLang error compiling ASSERT_FALSE(false)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, googletest

I downloaded [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) and built it in a subdirectory named `build`.
Then, I wrote the following code in a file named `main.cpp`:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
TEST(FOO, BAR) { ASSERT_FALSE(false); }
```

Quite simple indeed.
It relies on the fact that a `main` function is already provided with *googletest* if you link the `libgtestmain.a` library.

GCC (v5.3.1) compiles it using the following command:

```
g++ -L./googletest/build/googlemock/gtest -L./googletest/build/googlemock -I./googletest/googletest/include/ -lgmock -lgtest -lgtest_main -lgmock_main -pthread -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

Anyway, clang (v3.6.2) does not compile using the same command:

```
clang++ -L./googletest/build/googlemock/gtest -L./googletest/build/googlemock -I./googletest/googletest/include/ -lgmock -lgtest -lgtest_main -lgmock_main -pthread -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

The error is the following one:

> /tmp/main-4127ae.o: In function 'FOO_BAR_Test::TestBody()':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `testing::internal::GetBoolAssertionFailureMessage(testing::AssertionResult const&, char const*, char const*, char const*)'
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The code contains almost the sole `ASSERT_FALSE(false)` statement (that's a minimal, complete example and still it doesn't compile), so I'd say that the problem is not in the code itself.
The same problem arises also from the following statement:

```
TEST(FOO, BAR) { ASSERT_TRUE(true); }
```

Is that an issue due to *googletest*, to *clang* or whatever?
I'm trying to figure it out, but I'm a little bit in trouble while looking at the code of *googletest*.

**NOTE**

I've not been able to find neither an open nor a closed issue for *googletest*, so I'm to open also a ticket for it on *github*.
In a while I'll probably post the link to the issue.

Comment: maybe that's ABI incompatability because you built gtest using gcc and you link it to something that's compiled with clang?

Comment: Probably unrelated to the compilation error, but you should be linking against either `libgtest_main.a` or `libgmock_main.a`, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of GCC 5.1, g++ is not ABI-compatible with clang++. Some
bug reports: [clang++ no longer ABI-compatible with g++](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-3.6/+bug/1488254)
and [Add support for gcc's attribute abi_tag (needed for compatibility with gcc 5's libstdc++)](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23529).

Till this is fixed you need to link googletest-ing projects
with googletest libraries built with the same compiler.